# razorengine email templates(unable to compile)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

i am trying to parse my email templates with this line. I am using [razorengine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/)

```
 public string Converttemplate(Guid RecordId, string str,string Redirecto)
    {          
        string str1 = string.Empty;
        if (Redirecto == "Quotation")
        {
            var quot = QuotationService.GetQuotationForDetails(RecordId);

            str1 = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse<QuotationForDetailsViewModel>(str, quot);
        }

        return str1;
    }
```

basically str consist of something like this

```
Dear @Model.CustomerId
Your QuotationId @Model.QuotationNo is created , 
Your Sincerely Admin
```

this will parse correctly as both the @Model.CustomerId and @Model.QuotationNo contains in the **quot** model.

but if i replace @Model.CustomerId with @Model.CustomerName which doesn't exist in the quot **model** model then it will give **unable to compile error** ?

i am sure that this would have been handled in the framework!!. how can i solve this problem?

Edit

```
public QuotationForDetailsViewModel GetQuotationForDetails(Guid QuotationId)
    {
        var query = (from quot in _context.Quotations
                     where quot.QuotationId == QuotationId
                     select new QuotationForDetailsViewModel
                     {
                         AgencyName = quot.Agency.AgencyName,
                         AgencyScopeName = quot.QuotationScope.ScopeName,
                         CustomerId=quot.CustomerId,
                         CustomerName = quot.Customer.CompanyName,                    
                         PortName = quot.Port.PortName,
                         Vessel=quot.Vessel.CurrentName,
                         VesselId=quot.VesselId,
                         PortId = quot.Port.PortId,
                         IsJvFull=quot.isJvFull,                    
                         ETA = quot.ETA,
                         NRT = quot.NRT,
                         GRT = quot.GRT,
                         isJobInitiated = quot.isJobInitiated,
                         isCancelled = quot.isCancelled,
                         IsJvCreated=quot.IsJVCreated,
                         IsFullyTaxable=quot.isFullyTaxable,
                         IsFinalInvoiceCreated=quot.FinalInvoiceCreated,
                         IsInitialInvoiceCreated=quot.initialInvoiceCreated,
                         PerDay =quot.PerDay,
                         TaxRate= quot.TaxRate,
                         TotalPkr = quot.TotalAmountPKR,
                         TotalUSD = quot.TotalAmountUSD,
                         RateTerminal = quot.RateTerminalId,
                         QuoteDate = quot.QuoteDate,
                         Quantity = quot.Quantity,
                         UpFrontCriteria=quot.UpfrontCriteria,
                         UpFrontFee=quot.UpfrontFee,
                         UpFrontPercentage=quot.UpfrontPercentage,
                         UpFrontCurrencyId=quot.UpfrontCurrencyId,
                         QuotationNo = quot.QuotationNo,
                         QuotationId=quot.QuotationId,
                         ExchangeRate=quot.ExchangeRate,
                         TransactionExchangeRate=quot.TransactionExchangeRate,
                         Terminal = quot.QuotationBerths.Select(m => m.Terminal.TerminalName).ToList(),
                         Purposeofcallcargo = quot.QuotationPurposeOfCalls.Select(m => m.PurposeOfCall.PurposeOfCallName).ToList(),
                         CargoType = quot.QuotationCargoCategories.Select(m => m.CargoCategory.CargoCategoryName).ToList(),
                         PortServiceTariffIncluded = (from service in quot.QuotationServices
                                                      select new PortServiceDetailViewModel
                                                      {
                                                          Id = service.QuotationServicesId,
                                                          Isstage=service.InvoiceStage,
                                                          ServiceId = service.PortServicesTariffId,
                                                          ServiceName = service.PortServicesTariff.ServiceName,
                                                          ServiceCriteria = service.PortServicesTariff.PortServiceCriteria.CriteriaName,
                                                          ItemBasis = service.PortServicesTariff.PortServiceItemBasi.ItemBasisName,
                                                          ServiceCriteriaId = service.PortServicesTariff.PortServiceCriteria.CriteriaId,
                                                          ItemBasisId = service.PortServicesTariff.PortServiceItemBasi.ItemBasisId,
                                                          Rate = service.Rate,
                                                          Amount = service.Amount,
                                                          TotalPKR=service.AmountPKR,
                                                          TotalUSD=service.AmountUSD,
                                                          IsCancelled= service.IsCancelled,
                                                          InvoicedAmountUSD=service.InvoicedAmountUSD,
                                                          InvoicedAmountPKR= service.InvoicedAmountPKR,
                                                          ActualAmountPKR=service.ActualAmountPKR,
                                                          ActualAmountUSD=service.ActualAmountUSD,   
                                                          VendorDate=service.VendorDate,
                                                          PrincipleDate=service.PrincipleDate,
                                                          IsPrinciple = service.Customer.PartyTypeId == 1 ? true : false,
                                                          BilledTo =service.BilledTo,
                                                          BillerName=service.Customer.CompanyName,
                                                          VendorId=service.VendorGUID,
                                                          VendorName=service.Customer1.CompanyName,                                                                
                                                          Currency = service.PortServicesTariff.Currency.CurrencyName
                                                      }).ToList()

                     }).FirstOrDefault();
        return query;
```

Comment: try puting `@model dynamic` at the top of the tempalte or `@model YourProject.QuotationForDetailsViewModel`  
p.s. razor engine has moved to github > https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Comment: it doesn't works but intalling github dll eloborated the error more

Comment: Unable to compile template. 'Alpine_Dev.Models.QuotationForDetailsViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'CustomerIds' and no extension method 'CustomerIds' accepting a first argument of type 'Alpine_Dev.Models.QuotationForDetailsViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you show me your view model? Because it looks hat you don't have `CustomerIds` in it.

Comment: no i don't have customerids in it. what i am trying to achieve here is that if razor found the property replace it and if it doesn't find the property leave it as it is.

Comment: this scenario can be achieve with razorengine?

Comment: you can use the following line : `@(Model.CustomerIds ?? "")` but actually it looks that you have a typo in your property name in the view itself. shouldn't it be `@Model.CustomerId` instead of `@Modle.CustomerId**s**`

Comment: So the thing i want to confirm is that i will really have to supply all the parameters other wise it will give error? i can't get away with writing @Model.CustomerIds?

Comment: basically in my case email will be created by the client. i will be giving him the parameter list from which he can choose and applied that in his mail. so it is really pointless to use this as he can make some mistake here. any other framework you or anybody can recommend?

Comment: @maz3tt: Correct, a razor template is strongly typed. If you try to access a property that doesn't exist it will throw a compilation error just like it would in any other part of your code. Using the dynamic keyword won't help either unless your model is specifically a dynamic type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support 'invalid' property-names/methods/events... you need to use `dynamic` and write your own wrapper:

```
public class MyWrapper : DynamicObject
{
    private dynamic _inner;
    public MyWrapper(dynamic inner) {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        try {
            // Dynamically invoke binder.Name on _inner (you can use reflection for example)
            // Another way is to use https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface:
            result = new Invocation(InvocationKind.Get, binder.Name).InvokeWithStoredArgs(_inner);
        } catch {
            // RazorEngine should ignore this.
            result = "";
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you only need to give that wrapper to `RazorEngine`. You can override more methods of `DynamicObject` and forward them to support more scenarios (but you should get the idea).